# Find a specific implementation in a generic container

Tags: c++, c++11, generics

I have a container which contains A-s.

B, C, D, E, ... implement A.

What is the most efficient & safest way of finding for example the first C object? (so the first objects, whose type is C)

I thought about unordered_map with < string, A > but strings aren't very safe because they are only checked runtime.

Comment: Do you mean find the first element of *type* `C`? Or first element *containing* `C`?

Comment: And what is it you want to accomplish by this? What is the *actual* and *original* problem you want to solve? Can't it be solved with virtual functions and polymorphism? Lastly some [related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Sorry. I want to implement a component system on an entity. And I would like to access one specific component of the entity.

Comment: So, for example the string, is referencing the type of implemented entity?

Comment: Yes, one solution would be that, but strings are only checked runtime, so they arent very safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know which way is more efficient is to test it on your platform and measure times, comparing different ways to solve it.

I sugest, for example, the use of enums to accelerate the search and indexing of the tree.

```
enum objType
{
   A = 1,
   B,
   C,
   D
};
```

The container maybe should be:

```
 unordered_map < objType, A* >
```

But if you need to store more than one object of a type, you shuld consider use of multimap

```
 unordered_multimap < objType, A* >
```

Comment: Instead of an enum, I would suggest `std::type_index`.

Comment: And what if I would like to store 2 B-s? There would be 2 values with the same key. Is that possible?

Comment: You are rigth, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/    Container properties, "No two elements in the container can have equivalent keys." Maybe you could use another container, or a nested container for all of your B-s.